# MySQL Workbench with Heroku

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, heroku, workbench

I have made an application with CodeIgniter with a MySQL database. I'm using Heroku to deploy my application, and have done so successfully. However, I'm having problems with using my database on Heroku. Locally I'm using XAMPP and phpmyadmin for all database work.

In Heroku, I've used a clearDB add on to support MySQL and have gotten all necessary credentials in the format:

mysql://DB_USERNAME:DB_PASSWORD@BD_HOST/DB_DATABASE?reconnect=true

I've used MySQL Workbench and have created a database using the above supplied host name, username, password and have successfully imported the tables, columns and data from my already existing database.

Now, I'm unsure on how to proceed. Do I export my database from Workbench? or what am I supposed to do to be able to use my database on Heroku.

Any and all help appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. please don't tell me to use Postgres

Answer (score 0):

Update: So I figued I didn't have to do anything, once the databse is configured on Workbench, all I had to do was refresh my heroku web page and it works.